# table Expenses has no column named category

Tags: java, android, sqlite

i'm trying to create a table in an SQLite Database in Android and for some reason it isn't working. My code seems fine, can someone help me see what i'm doing wrong?

TableData.java

```
public class TableData {

public TableData(){

}

public static abstract class TableInfo implements BaseColumns{

    public static final String EXPENSE_NAME = "name";
    public static final String EXPENSE_COST = "cost";
    public static final String EXPENSE_CATEGORY = "category";
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "AquariumApp";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Expenses";

}
 }
```

DatabadeOperations.java

```
public class DatabaseOperations extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final int database_version = 2;
public String CREATE_QUERY = "CREATE TABLE " + TableInfo.TABLE_NAME + "(" + TableInfo.EXPENSE_NAME + " TEXT," + TableInfo.EXPENSE_COST + " TEXT," + TableInfo.EXPENSE_CATEGORY + " TEXT );";

public DatabaseOperations (Context context){
    super(context, TableInfo.DATABASE_NAME, null, database_version);
    Log.d("Database operations", "Database successfully created");
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sdb){
    sdb.execSQL(CREATE_QUERY);
    Log.d("Database operations", "Table created");
}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2){

}

public void putInformation(DatabaseOperations dop, String name, String cost, String category){
    SQLiteDatabase SQ = dop.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(TableInfo.EXPENSE_NAME, name);
    cv.put(TableInfo.EXPENSE_COST, cost);
    cv.put(TableInfo.EXPENSE_CATEGORY, category);
    long k = SQ.insert(TableInfo.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
    Log.d("Database operations", "One row inserted.");

}
 }
```

AddExpense.java

```
public class AddExpense extends AppCompatActivity {

//EditText NameExpense = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
//EditText CostExpense = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
EditText expenseName, expenseCost;
RadioGroup expenseCategory;
RadioButton radioButton;
String expenseNameString, expenseCostString, radiobutt, expenseCategoryString;
Button REG;
Context ctx = this;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_expense);
    setTitle("Add Expense");

    expenseName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.expenseName);

    expenseCost = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.expenseCost);

    expenseCategory = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.RadioGroup);

    REG = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    REG.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            expenseNameString = expenseName.getText().toString();
            expenseCostString = expenseCost.getText().toString();

            // get selected radio button from radioGroup
            int selectedId = expenseCategory.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

            // find the radiobutton by returned id
            radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);

            expenseCategoryString = radioButton.getText().toString();

            DatabaseOperations DB = new DatabaseOperations(ctx);
            DB.putInformation(DB, expenseNameString, expenseCostString, expenseCategoryString);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Expense Added!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });


}
```

This is the error i'm getting. 
[image]

Comment: if you are getting any errors please post them

Comment: @RaviTeja Added! thank you :)

Comment: if you added the column later try updating the database version.

Comment: add `onCreate(arg0);` in your update method.